# not getting missed call value from call logs android

Tags: android, calllog

hey I am unable to get the call type == missed call and of current date only.
Its can be achieved from Cursor query i have tried this but getting Calls type as missed call
I am using this in onCreate method but not getting any value in logcat????
Here is my piece of code any help would be greatly appreciated......thanks in advance

```
String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE+"="+CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;
    int missedtype=CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;
    String missed=Integer.toString(missedtype);

    String timestamp = String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());

    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver()
            .query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                            CallLog.Calls._ID },
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?" + " and "
                            + CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=?",
                    new String[] { timestamp, String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) },
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    //Cursor managedCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">= ?", new String[]{timestamp}, null);
     //Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,   null, where , null, CallLog.Calls.DATE+ " >= ?");

        int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);    
        {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String LogphNumber = cursor.getString(number);  
            String callType = cursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = cursor.getString(date);              
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
    {

        if(cursor.getCount()>1){

           System.out.println("Total Logs::>>>>>>>>> "+cursor.getCount());
           System.out.println("\nPhoneNo:----"+LogphNumber);            
           System.out.println("\nCallDate: "+callDayTime);
           System.out.println("\nCallDuration in Seconds :"+callDuration);
           System.out.println("\n-----------------------");

       }else if(cursor.getCount()==0){
           System.out.println("No Missed calls");
       }
    }
        }cursor.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String timestamp = String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver()
            .query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                            CallLog.Calls._ID },
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?" + " and "
                            + CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=?",
                    new String[] { timestamp, String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) },
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE);
```

Comment: Hey its giving an error in my log:                               02-28 12:09:42.484: E/AndroidRuntime(20312): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
02-28 12:09:42.484: E/AndroidRuntime(20312):  at com.example.demo.MainActivity.getCallDetails(MainActivity.java:129)

Comment: Can you paste some code snippets about getCallDetails()?And I edit my answer,I change the *new String[] {timestamp, CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE}* to *new String[] {timestamp, String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE)}*.It works fine for me.

Comment: I think you tried to access data by the wrong column index.

Comment: Now i am getting this in my Log cat instead of any value:                                                                  02-28 12:35:08.683: D/(31807): GPU monitor inactive - could not find libgpumonitor.so [(null)] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.gpumonitor = 0)
02-28 12:35:08.683: I/brcm-gr(31807): [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933

Comment: I have run your code but it still works fine for me.I just changed *getTodayTimestamp()* to *new Date().getTime()* and *CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?"* to *CallLog.Calls.DATE + "<?"*.Because    I think the call date later than today is meaningless.Are you sure that new error came from your application?

Comment: yes i m sure that after changing the code what u suggest gives, above error as:"gpu monitor inactive error". Can you give your code what you are testing so by replacing yours i can achieve what i want????

Comment: I just implement getTodayTimestamp() as *private long getTodayTimestamp() {
  return new Date().getTime();
 }*